# How do you write log to the base e?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I was given a question, find $f'(1)$ of $f(x) = \ln \sqrt{2-x}$.

So I wrote

$$1/2 \ln (2-x)^{(-1/2)(-1)} = -1/2 \ln (2-x)^{-1/2}$$
$$= -(1/2\ln)/\sqrt{2-x}$$

But when I sub in $x = 1$ I get a SYNTAX error, I realised log base e cannot be put in my calculator. I don't know how to put this into my calculator, can anyone help? Thanks!!

Comment: $\log_a b = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$. This is the change of base law.

Comment: Why do you change from $\;\ln\;$ to $\;\log\;$ in the middle of the calculations? That can only contribute to confusion. You can use $\;\log\;$ all the way from the beginning.

Comment: Please check my edit $\ln$ is the natural logarithm, hence $\log_e$

Comment: @MrYouMath Your editing has a mistake in the last mathematical expression: that backsla\sh does not belong there.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I just added dollar signs and turned the function like $\ln$ and $\sqrt{.}$ into LaTeX the last line was strange from the beginning :D. I hope the op does correct the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Given,
$$ f(x) = \ln \sqrt{2-x} $$

Use chain rule to differentiate.

$$ f^{'}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x}}\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2-x}} (-1) $$

So, at $x=1$,

$$f^{'}(1) = \frac{-1}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\ln(\sqrt{2-x})=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2-x)$, hence $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2-x}\cdot(-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule, and since

$$\begin{cases}\left(\sqrt{2-x}\right)'=-\cfrac1{2\sqrt{2-x}}\\{}\\
\left(\log x\right)'=\cfrac1x\end{cases}\implies\left(\log\sqrt{2-x}\right)'=-\frac1{2\sqrt{2-x}}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{2-x}}=-\frac1{2(2-x)}$$

for $\;x<2\;$, certainly.